# extract case classes from json file scala play

Tags: json, scala, play-json

im trying to extract my data from json into a case class without success.

the Json file:

```
 [
  {
    "name": "bb",
    "loc": "sss",
    "elements": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "loc": "firstHere",
        "elements": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "ca",
    "loc": "sss",
    "elements": []
  }
]
```

my code :

```
      case class ElementContainer(name : String, location : String,elements : Seq[ElementContainer])
      object elementsFormatter  {
        implicit val elementFormatter = Json.format[ElementContainer]
      }

    object Applicationss extends App  {

      val el = new ElementContainer("name1", "firstHere", Seq.empty)
      val el1Cont = new ElementContainer("bb","sss", Seq(el))

      val source:String=Source.fromFile("src/bin/elementsTree.json").getLines.mkString
  val jsonFormat = Json.parse(source)
  val r1= Json.fromJson[ElementContainer](jsonFormat)
}
```

after running this im getting inside r1:

> JsError(List((/elements,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/name,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/location,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))

been trying to extract this data forever, please advise

Comment: The names of the elements in the JSON should match the names of the corresponding variables in the case class (when you're using the default `Json.format` formatter). So for instance `location` should be renamed to `loc`.

Comment: check this tutorial on how to parse json to case classes: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/ and http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json-part2/  hope it helps understanding how to parse json correctly using play. Note: https://github.com/travisbrown/circe seems to be more powerful and easy to use than Play JSON

Comment: thx for your answers, very informative and helpful ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `location` instead `loc` and, you'll need to parse file into a `Seq[ElementContainer]`, since it's an array, not a single `ElementContainer`:

```
Json.fromJson[Seq[ElementContainer]](jsonFormat)
```

Also, you have the `validate` method that will return you either errors or parsed json object..

Comment: Note that you're missing []'s in the `fromJson` call. It should be `Json.fromJson[Seq[ElementContainer]](jsonFormat)`

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to upvote and/or mark as correct answer! :p